List containers/folders/subfolders in Azure DataLake in Python
I have a python code snippet to connect to Azure. The functions are to connect, get the containers, and get the blobs of the container.
The get_containers() can already list the up to the first folder, problem is I cannot get the subfolders.
The directory structure in Azure looks something like (this is also my desired output):
container1
container1/folder1/subfolder2
container1/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3
container1/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4
container1/folder2
container1/folder3/subfolder5
container2
container2/folder4
container2/folder5/subfolder6
container2/folder6
container3
container3/folder7/subfolder7
container4
container4/folder8
container4/folder9

and it could possible change. I need to list or print the containers/folders/subfolders in a dynamic way.
Here is the snippet of the functions:
    def _authenticate(self):
        """Authenticates using ClientSecretCredential and returns BlobServiceClient."""
        try:
            credential = ClientSecretCredential(
                tenant_id=self.tenant_id,
                client_id=self.client_id,
                client_secret=self.client_secret
            )
            blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
                account_url=self.account_url,
                credential=credential
            )
            print("Successfully connected to Azure Blob Storage!")
            return blob_service_client
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to authenticate: {str(e)}')
            return None

    def get_containers(self):
        """Lists containers and their subdirectories in Azure Blob Storage."""
        if self.blob_service_client:
            try:
                container_list = []
                containers = self.blob_service_client.list_containers()

                for container in containers:
                    container_name = container['name']
                    container_list.append(container_name)

                    # List blobs and subdirectories in each container
                    container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
                    blobs = container_client.walk_blobs()

                    for blob in blobs:
                        container_list.append(f'{container_name}/{blob.name}')

                return container_list
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Failed to list containers: {str(e)}')
                return []
        else:
            print("Service Client not initialized")
            return []

    def get_blobs(self, container_name: str, directory: str = "/") -> list:
        """Lists all blobs in the specified container and directory."""
        if self.blob_service_client:
            try:
                container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
                blobs = container_client.walk_blobs(name_starts_with=directory)

                blob_list = []
                for blob in blobs:
                    blob_list.append(f'{container_name}/{blob.name}')

                return blob_list

            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Failed to list blobs in {container_name}: {str(e)}')
                return []
        else:
            print("Service Client not initialized")
            return []

The output I got is:
container1
container1/folder1
container1/folder2
container1/folder3
container2
container2/folder4
container2/folder5
container2/folder6
container3
container3/folder7
container4
container4/folder8
container4/folder9

is there someething missing from my get_containers() that I only get up to the first folder and not the subfolders?

You are on the right track. To list all folders and subfolders, you would need to call your get_blobs method recursively.
Please see the code below:
depth = 0
indent = "  "

def list_blobs_hierarchical(self, container_client: ContainerClient, prefix):
    for blob in container_client.walk_blobs(name_starts_with=prefix, delimiter='/'):
        if isinstance(blob, BlobPrefix):# check if the blob you got is a folder.
            # Indentation is only added to show nesting in the output
            print(f"{self.indent * self.depth}{blob.name}")
            self.depth += 1
            self.list_blobs_hierarchical(container_client, prefix=blob.name)
            self.depth -= 1
        else:
            # this is the actual blob in the folder. you can choose to ignore it.
            print(f"{self.indent * self.depth}{blob.name}")

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-python#use-a-hierarchical-listing

Thanks for this! This works! Updated my code to add this and call it recursively.
